# QMessageLogger and thread safety

Tags: multithreading, qt, logging, thread-safety

Is the QMassgeLogger thread safe? Can I use QMessageLogger in a multithreading environment?

I m using Qt 5.9 on an embedded platform.

Comment: Multi-threaded applications are supported. Although all of the default functionality is thread-safe, care does need to be taken to ensure correct record ordering when multiple threads are accessing the same log.  [Logging Events With BoostLog](https://www.ics.com/blog/logging-events-boostlog)